# How to keep a check on the "date value" on JSP page as I have modified the date in the setter if it is null

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, date

I have some trouble with my jsp page's date value. Basically I have a date picker which allows me to pick date and save it to database. If I do not pick a date, the value is null which I check before setting it and passing it to the database. If its null, I modify it to a dummy date and then save it to database. This part works fine. But if the jsp page throws the not null validation, the value goes to the setter as null, gets modified there to the dummy value and reflected back in the form. I don't want that dummy value to be visible to the user. So is there any way I can put a check on the jsp page so that if the value is a dummy date value it will be visible as null to the user?

```
<b>Order Information</b>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orId" path="orId" cssErrorClass="error">* Order Id :</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orId" size="35" maxlength="35" /> <form:errors path="orId" /></td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orServicetag" path="orServicetag" cssErrorClass="error">* Service tag:</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orServicetag" size="35" maxlength="35" value= "${ticketList.ticServicetag}"/> <form:errors path="orServicetag" /></td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orOwnerSUUsername" path="orOwnerSUUsername" cssErrorClass="error">* SU UserName:</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orOwnerSUUsername" id="suusnm" size="35" maxlength="35"  value= "${ticketList.ticOwnerSuUsername}"/> <form:errors path="orOwnerSUUsername" /></td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orTicId" path="orTicId" cssErrorClass="error">* Ticket Id</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orTicId" id="ticcrdt" size="35" maxlength="35" value= "${ticketList.ticId}"/> <form:errors path="orTicId" /></td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orTicCreatedDate" path="orTicCreatedDate" cssErrorClass="error">* Ticket Date (YYYY-MM-DD):</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orTicCreatedDate" size="35" maxlength="35" value= "${ticketList.ticDate}"/> <form:errors path="orTicCreatedDate" /></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orPartOrdered" path="orPartOrdered" cssErrorClass="error">* Part Name :</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orPartOrdered" size="35" maxlength="35" /> <form:errors path="orPartOrdered" /></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orOrderedDate" path="orOrderedDate" cssErrorClass="error">* Part Ordered Date (YYYY-MM-DD):</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orOrderedDate" id="datepicker1" size="35" maxlength="35" /> <form:errors path="orOrderedDate" /></td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orRecievedDate" path="orRecievedDate" cssErrorClass="error"> Part Received Date (YYYY-MM-DD):</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left"><form:input path="orRecievedDate" id="datepicker2" size="35" maxlength="35" /> <form:errors path="orRecievedDate" /></td>  
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><form:label for="orStatus" path="orStatus" cssErrorClass="error">* Order Status:</form:label></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <select name="orStatus" id = "orStatus" id="slectboxid1">
                                <option value = "">---Select---</option>
                                <option value="Open">Open</option>
                                <option value="Progress">Progress</option>
                                <option value="Part Ordered">Part Ordered</option>
                                <option value="Part Arrived">Part Arrived/ Received</option>
                                <option value="Waiting for Owner's computer">Waiting for Owner's computer</option>
                                <option value="Installation">Installation in progress</option>
                                <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
                            </select>   
                            <form:errors path="orStatus" /></td>    
                    </tr>   
            </table>

            <div align="center" style="margin-top:15px;" >
            <form action="OrderDatabase" method="get">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Order"/>
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/> |
                <input type="reset" name="reset"/>
            </form>
            </div>
</form:form>
```

The Code for the ticketDetailsBean is as follows:

```
    package com.helplaw.beans;

    //import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class OrderDetailsBean {
private String orId;
private String orPartOrdered;
private Date orTicCreatedDate;
private Date orOrderedDate;
private Date orRecievedDate;
private String orOwnerSUUsername;
private String orServicetag;
private String orStatus;
private int orTicId;

public String getOrId() {
    return orId;
}
public void setOrId(String orId) {
    this.orId = orId;
}
public String getOrPartOrdered() {
    return orPartOrdered;
}
public void setOrPartOrdered(String orPartOrdered) {
    this.orPartOrdered = orPartOrdered;
}
public Date getOrTicCreatedDate() {
    return  orTicCreatedDate;
}
public void setOrTicCreatedDate(Date orTicCreatedDate) {
    this.orTicCreatedDate = orTicCreatedDate;
}
public Date getOrOrderedDate() {
    return orOrderedDate;
}
public void setOrOrderedDate(Date orOrderedDate) {
    this.orOrderedDate = orOrderedDate;
}
public Date getOrRecievedDate() {
    return orRecievedDate;
}
public void setOrRecievedDate(Date orRecievedDate) {
    if(orRecievedDate == null){
        System.out.println("d11:" + orRecievedDate);
        this.orRecievedDate = new Date(000000001);
    }
    else if(orRecievedDate.toString().equals("1969-12-31")){
        System.out.println("d12:" + orRecievedDate);
        this.orRecievedDate = null;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("d13:" + orRecievedDate);
        this.orRecievedDate = orRecievedDate;
    }
}
public String getOrOwnerSUUsername() {
    return orOwnerSUUsername;
}
public void setOrOwnerSUUsername(String orOwnerSUUsername) {
    this.orOwnerSUUsername = orOwnerSUUsername;
}
public String getOrServicetag() {
    return orServicetag;
}
public void setOrServicetag(String orServicetag) {
    this.orServicetag = orServicetag;
}
public String getOrStatus() {
    return orStatus;
}
public void setOrStatus(String orStatus) {
    this.orStatus = orStatus;
}
public int getOrTicId() {
    return orTicId;
}
public void setOrTicId(int orTicId) {
    this.orTicId = orTicId;
}


}
```

Comment: Is it the case for all the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the NULL validation because it will never be null in your case where you are always setting a dummy value.

---

Alternatively, you can achieve it using `hidden input` field.

#### Steps to follow:

- create hidden input fields one for each date input field.
- set the value in hidden input field if value is changed in actual date input field using JavaScript
- now set the dummy value in hidden input field rather than actual input field if value is null
- read values from hidden input fields to save it in database

---

***Note:*** swap the `path` attribute date input field with hidden input fields so that it will be picked from hidden input fields when form is submitted.

Comment: Why you have placed a validation where it will never be null. You are always passing a default dummy value. Then it will never be null at all.

Comment: If I comment out this validation it gives me a null pointer exception

Comment: How come is it possible? Try with alternative solution.

Comment: I think I will try the hidden field option. That seems useful. I will let you know if I get some other problem with it. Thanks

Comment: Hey Braj,can you help me with the above code to place in the hidden field. I have edited the question to include the TicketDetailsBean also I tried doing it but there is some error with the path for the input field